# Data disappears after the page is refreshed

Tags: angular

I need to store data in the shopping cart for an online store. What can do to prevent the data from disappearing after the page is refreshed? Is it better data to store them in a database or use localStorage?

```
public list: Order[] = [];

add(order_list: OrderList) {
    const orderList: Order = Object.assign({}, {
        name: order_list.name,
        description: order_list.description,
        cost: order_list.cost,
        quantity: order_list.quantity,
        order_id: order_list.order_list_id
    });
    const possible = this.list.find(i => i.order_id === orderList.order_id);
    if (possible) {
        possible.quantity += orderList.quantity;
    } else {
        this.list.push(orderList);
    }
    this.computerPrice();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think keeping them in the browser is a better approach. The server will not need to remember and fetch previous data.

- You will implement a simpler method in backend

If you think that your customer will need their shipping list across devices, save the list in the database, otherwise localStorrage, cookies are enough.

Answer (score 0):

You can use localstorage to save the product, to prevent server side call but issue with this approach is you can't track which customer has added what in cart, this information helps alot for sending notification to complete order also help e commerce to track most liked product etc..
Use both localstorage and server side combined  You can send saved cart details to server on specific event all together, so even if user change machine cart value will be retained.
Below example is of node js and mongodb:
https://medium.com/javascript-in-plain-english/building-a-shopping-cart-in-node-js-bdbe02614eb9

Answer (score 0):

Two cases:

- The user ins't logged => local storage.
- The user is logged => if you expect a lot of cross device usage, it's better to store it server-side.

To store locally, if you use ngrx, create a meta reducer. It's easy and the example of meta reducer in the doc is doing just that. If you don't use ngrx or any kind of redux/state, refactor the project to use one.

To store on the server, i would use a simple json field in the database and filter it on reception to ensure that all the references still exist, drop those who aren't available anymore (directly in the service that load the data and call the corresponding load action). It's simple and don't require a complicated object model.

In both case simply store the list of object using ids (and not name, description, etc) and quantities. Use relational logic here and build it in the corresponding redux selector. Otherwise prices won't be up to date, as well as quantities, available etc.